# OSGI, Java, Netbeans, and Swing -> Basic working example?

Tags: java, netbeans, osgi

Some background: I am trying to find the equivalent of a .dll for Java. Having read some information off of the internet, I've come to believe that OSGi might be a better option than the more 'manual' way of loading JARs and instantiating objects. However, the information on OSGi seems awful thick, and the examples seem rather lacking.

I've added the latest OSGi JAR from a link on the Eclipse page. My project is written in Swing, and my IDE is Netbeans. Now I need some decent examples (basic ones) of how exactly this OSGi system is supposed to work. If this were a .dll, I'd be ensuring a common interface that I could use to call functions / instantiate objects after loading the .dll...but, again, having read through several pages on a 'basic' OSGi design, I come to the conclusion that I understand perhaps three words of it.

Can anyone offer up the idiot's version of OSGi, whereby you have both the code for the JAR / plugin & its interface, as well as an example of it being loaded / called from within an app?

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples on the internet (not necessarily Swing applications, as you already know). I would suggest that you start with a basic small hello world example (with no UI).

Adding a Swing user interface, is *more or less trivial* once you understand your ecosystem well. It will also help evaluate how you can take an existing non OSGI application and slowly make it fully OSGI-based.

Making an existing large application fully OSGI-based is not necessarily a straightforward exercise, something that you also probably already know.

Below is a link to an IPOJO Swing example that should help you get started.
http://felix.apache.org/site/ipojo-in-10-minutes.html

From my experience, it's not that straightforward to take an existing application and move it to OSGI, especially applications that are already huge.

It's better to have OSGI since the beginning, as it forces you to think about services/bundles cooperation, bundles exporting, decoupling, etc.

Hope it helps